# Check if Path.exists() was called once with mock.path in a unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I need to know if `Path.exists()` was called. I want to do that in a unittest but allways got the answer that it was not called.

I assume something is wrong with the import path. I know from the docs and some blog-posts that this can be tricky.

This is the "productive" code:

```
import pathlib

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, file_path: pathlib.Path):
        if not file_path.exists():
            print('Not good.')
        else:
            print('Fine.')
```

And this is the unittest for it

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock
import pathlib

import mycode

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('pathlib.Path')
    def test_mycode(self, mock_path):
        mypath = pathlib.Path('bar')
        foo = mycode.Foo(mypath)

        mock_path.exists.assert_called_once()
```

But the error is still

> AssertionError: Expected 'exists' to have been called once. Called 0
> times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @slideshowp2 is fine and working. And it pointed me to the right solution better fitting to my own MWE.

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('pathlib.Path')
    def test_mycode(self, mocked_path):
        foo = mycode.Foo(mocked_path)
        mocked_path.exists.assert_called_once()
```

The problem with my code was that I instantiated a real object of `pathlib.Path`. But the key of the solution is to use the mock object `mocked_path` because this is a surrogate for a real `Path` object.

In my questions intial code the `Foo.__init__()` never used the mocked object but the real `pathlib.Path`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create mock for `pathlib.Path` using [create_autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#create-autospec) helper function.  And pass this mock object to the constructor of the `Foo` class.

> Functions or methods being mocked will have their arguments checked to ensure that they are called with the correct signature.

E.g. (*Python 3.9.6*)

`foo.py`:

```py
import pathlib


class Foo():
    def __init__(self, file_path: pathlib.Path):
        if not file_path.exists():
            print('Not good.')
        else:
            print('Fine.')
```

`foo_test.py`:

```py
import unittest
import pathlib
from unittest.mock import create_autospec
from foo import Foo


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Foo_file_path_exists(self):
        mock_path = create_autospec(pathlib.Path)
        mock_path.exists.return_value = True
        Foo(mock_path)
        mock_path.exists.assert_called_once()

    def test_Foo_file_path_not_exists(self):
        mock_path = create_autospec(pathlib.Path)
        mock_path.exists.return_value = False
        Foo(mock_path)
        mock_path.exists.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test result:

```sh
Fine.
.Not good.
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.184s

OK
Name                                     Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/71945781/foo.py            6      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/71945781/foo_test.py      17      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                       23      0   100%
```

Comment: btw: How did you produced that test output?